trying to spawn different random enemies from a list
sorry if this is hard to understand, but im in the middle of making a space invaders game and instead of using the same picture for an enemy each time i want it to choose a random enemy from my list to spawn in but instead of spawning the random enemy, it just randomly goes through all the images really fast
import pygame
import random
import math

pygame.init()

# creating the screen

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# title and icon
pygame.display.set_caption('space invaders')

icon = pygame.image.load('spaceinvaders_logo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# player
playerimg = pygame.image.load('spaceinvader_ship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

# enemies
enemy1 = pygame.image.load('big_cropped_enemy1.png').convert()
enemy2 = pygame.image.load('big_cropped_enemy2.png').convert()
enemy3 = pygame.image.load('big_cropped_enemy3.png').convert()
enemy4 = pygame.image.load('big_cropped_enemy4.png').convert()
enemy5 = pygame.image.load('big_cropped_enemy5.png').convert()
enemy6 = pygame.image.load('big_cropped_enemy6.png').convert()

enemies = [enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, enemy4, enemy5, enemy6]
ememyimg = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0, 800)
enemyY = random.randint(50, 150)
enemyX_change = 2
enemyY_change = 40

# bullet
bulletimg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 18
# ready state means you cant see the bullet on the screen
# fire means the bullet is currently moving
bullet_state = 'ready'

# start menu
game_state = 'start menu'
start_menu = pygame.image.load("space invaders menu.png")

running = True


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(random.choice(enemies), (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state  
    bullet_state = 'fire'
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 27, y + 10))


def draw_start_menu():
    screen.blit(start_menu, (0, 0))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 60)
    font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 30)
    start_button = font2.render('Press SPACE to play!', True, (255, 255, 255))
    exit_button = font2.render('X  -  Exit', True, (255, 255, 255))

    screen.blit(start_button, (300, 300))

    screen.blit(exit_button, (355, 400))

    pygame.display.update()


def iscollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX-bulletX,2))+ (math.pow(enemyY-bulletY,2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False



while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    if game_state == 'start menu':
        draw_start_menu()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            game_state = "game"
            game_over = False
        if keys[pygame.K_x]:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    elif game_state == "game":

        screen.fill('black')
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            # thing moves when key press < >
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    playerX_change = -8
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_change = 8

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if bullet_state == 'ready':
                        # get the current x coordinate of spaceship
                        bulletX = playerX
                        fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_change = 0

        playerX += playerX_change

    # makes sure ship doesnt go off map
        if playerX <= 0:
            playerX = 0
        elif playerX >= 736:
            playerX = 736

    # enemy movement
        enemyX += enemyX_change

        if enemyX <= 0:
            enemyX_change = 2
            enemyY += enemyY_change
        elif enemyX >= 736:
            enemyX_change = -2
            enemyY += enemyY_change

    # bullet movement
        if bulletY <= 0:
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = 'ready'

        if bullet_state == 'fire':
            fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
            bulletY -= bulletY_change

        # collision
        collision = iscollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = 'ready'

        player(playerX, playerY)
        enemy(enemyX, enemyY)

        pygame.display.update()


So you want each enemy that you spawn to flicker between all your images randomly right?

@Zico I think you mistook the description of what they observe as error to be their description of what they try to achieve.

Ah, so I did. I'll edit the post to be a little more clear.

@zico yea its the opposite. the problem is that it is flickering between all the pictures when i dont want it to
